# Full outer join in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, union, outer-join, full-outer-join

I have the following table in Postgresql:

```
sch_code   sch_level   start_date   end_date      flag
1234          P        01-01-2018   31-01-2018    V
1234          S        01-01-2018   31-01-2018    V
5678          S        01-01-2018   31-01-2018    V
8965          P        01-01-2018   31-01-2018    V
```

The result which I require is as follows.

```
sch_code    start_P         end_P     start_S     end_S
1234        01-01-2018   31-01-2018   01-01-2018   31-01-2018  
5678        00-00-0000   00-00-0000   01-01-2018   31-01-2018  
8965        01-01-2018   31-01-2018   00-00-0000   00-00-0000
```

The queries which i tried with `UNION` did not provide a result. I have also tried using looped select statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` ([see guide here](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/full-outer-join)).
And since you can't use a `WHERE` filter due to potential `NULL` values, you have to pre-filter the 2 data sets using `CTE`s ([see guide here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)).

```
WITH pdata AS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sch_level='P'
),
sdata AS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sch_level='S'
)
SELECT
  COALESCE(pdata.sch_code, sdata.sch_code) AS sch_code,
  pdata.start_date AS start_P,
  pdata.end_date   AS end_P,
  sdata.start_date AS start_S,
  pdata.end_date   AS end_S
FROM pdata
FULL OUTER JOIN sdata ON pdata.sch_code = sdata.sch_code
```

If you don't want `NULL` values in your date fields, simply use `COALESCE` and provide default values in whichever data type you might be using.